# How to make constructor accept all type of iterators?

Tags: c++, class, templates, iterator

I am creating a custom Vector/ArrayList class. But i´m having troubles creating the iterative version of the constructor. The following code works, but the problem is when i want to create ArrayList like this:

`ArrayList arr(1, 5);`

The compiler doesn't know what version of the function should pick.

How can I solve this?

The constructors:

```
ArrayList(const size_type elem_amount, value_type elem) : arr_size { elem_amount }, arr_capacity{ elem_amount }
{
    array = std::uninitialized_fill_n(allocator.allocate(arr_size), arr_size, elem) - arr_size;
    first = array;
    last = array + arr_size - 1;
}


template<typename ITER>
ArrayList(ITER begin, ITER end) : arr_size{ static_cast<size_type>(end - begin) }, arr_capacity{ arr_size }
{
    std::uninitialized_copy(begin, end, array = allocator.allocate(arr_size));
    first = array;
    last = array + arr_size - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to constrain the template to only work when the template type is deduced to be an iterator type.  Since you do `arr_size{ static_cast<size_type>(end - begin) }` to initialize `size` this means that you expect the iterators to be random access.  We can check for that using the `iterator_category` of [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)  Doing that gives you

```
template<typename ITER, 
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<typename std::iterator_traits<ITER>::iterator_category, 
                                            std::random_access_iterator_tag>, bool> = true>
ArrayList(ITER begin, ITER end) : arr_size{ static_cast<size_type>(end - begin) }, arr_capacity{ arr_size }
{
    std::uninitialized_copy(begin, end, array = allocator.allocate(arr_size));
    first = array;
    last = array + arr_size - 1;
}
```

Comment: I would use `std::is_base_of_v` (with the argument order reversed) instead of `is_same_v`. This makes it easier to change to a less specific type, and future-proofs the code against C++20 `std::contiguous_iterator_tag`.

Comment: @aschepler Good call.  Was just thinking about that.  Edited it in.

Answer (score 3):

### With C++20 you can use concepts

Note that some compilers start supporting the new features of C++20, *including concepts*: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

So to differentiate between your two constructors, with C++20 you restrict the allowed template arguments using a concept type:

```
template<std::random_access_iterator ITER>
         // see comment by Nathan Oliver for using random_access_iterator 
ArrayList(ITER begin, ITER end)
: arr_size{ static_cast<size_type>(end - begin) }, arr_capacity{ arr_size }
{
    std::uninitialized_copy(begin, end, array = allocator.allocate(arr_size));
    first = array;
    last = array + arr_size - 1;
}
```

If you wish to define your own concept (no need to in this case, just for the sake of the exercise), you can define a concept for an Iterator:

```
template<typename ITER>
concept Iterator = requires {
    typename std::iterator_traits<ITER>::iterator_category;
};
```

Or, for the use in this case, a RandomAccessIterator:

```
template<typename ITER>
concept RandomAccessIterator = std::is_base_of_v <
    std::random_access_iterator_tag,
    typename std::iterator_traits<ITER>::iterator_category
>;
```

And use it the same as above, for example:

```
template<RandomAccessIterator ITER>
ArrayList(ITER begin, ITER end)  // ...
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/gBevvC

(Note that [RandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/iterator/RandomAccessIterator) should be part of ranges, but can be implemented on your own as above).

Comment: Do note that `input_iterator` is too weak of a contract.  doing `arr_size{ static_cast<size_type>(end - begin) }` requires at least random access iterators.

Comment: @NathanOliver - indeed. Fixed.